# Use of additional groups in dc.js dataCount widget

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm a bit confused with respect to the implementation of the dataCount widget in the dc.js framework.

```
countProjectsLaunched
    .dimension(ndx2)
    .group(all)
```

Managed to get the above to work, but the dimension appears to actually be a crossfilter object.

I wanted to implement a predefined group such as

```
var projectsLaunchedByWeeks = weeksStatus.group()
   .reduceSum(function(d) { return d.projects_launched; });
```

but I get the same problem each time:

```
_chart.group(...).value is not a function
```

How is it possible to implement a different grouping functions?

I want to be able to sum up the number of projects launched during a period, not just the entire recordset.

Thanks

Comment: Is this a task for a renderlet?

Comment: What will the "out of __" value be in this case? Is it possible you just want a [numberDisplay widget](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/docs/api-latest.md#dc.numberDisplay) here?

Comment: Thanks Gordon. The numberDisplay widget could be useful. I ended up using the "onFilter" listener and then set up a separate function to generate some HTML. Used a funky jQuery counter to animate the numbers as they changed.

Comment: Heh ok that's pretty much equivalent. Thanks for following up.